# Can I use Azure Event Grid topics to communicate domain events in a microservice architecture?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, azure-eventgrid

I am confused. When comparing the messages services offered by Microsoft Azure, we can choose between:

- Event Grid
- Event Hubs
- Service Bus
- (Azure Cache for Redis)

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services?toc=/azure/service-bus-messaging/toc.json#comparison-of-services) gives the following comparison:

[image]

Now I'd like to write a microservice application consisting of several components. Each component should communicate local domain events to a topic (pub/sub). This could be achieved by using Service Bus topics, RabbitMQ topics, and so on.

Besides writing an Azure Function, I wasn't able to find out if I can write an event handler in java, **consuming** events from an event grid topic (ideally in a spring-idiomatic way).

Is Azure Event Grid "only" for connecting Azure services together? Should I stick with Service Bus topics for such tasks? Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Event Grid (AEG) is an **eventing** Pub/Sub model for reliable distributing *an event interest* to the destination resource in the **PUSH** manner, in other words, the AEG doesn't require to host a listener/receiver to pull up the event message as it is required by Azure Service Bus and Azure Event Hubs.

More details about the event destination handlers can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-handlers). Note, that the webhook handler can be hosted anywhere.

In your scenario, the AEG enables to push the event messages to the destination resource such as an Azure Service Bus queue/topic and then handled like other ones.

Comment: Thx for replying. Your answer consolidates my perception that AEG is best suited if the event source is mainly an Azure resource (not an app/component). Other than that, I don't see why I should first send an event to AEG which forwards it to Service Bus and then ends up in my application...

Comment: From the Publisher side: yes, the Azure resources (see the list of sources https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview#event-sources) have a built in an eventing for resource interest and there is basically not another eventing alternative way. In the case of custom eventing interest (which it is also your case), the AEG offers the **Event Domains**, see more details for its usage in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-domains. Note, that the *Event Domains* allow to manage and audit eventing in your app/component.

Comment: From the Subscriber side: the AEG doesn't support a "subscription balancing", in other words, the event interest is delivered in FAN-OUT pattern in reliable way for each destination resource declared in the subscription. For example, when your app/component subscribed on the event interest in the cluster environment, all instances will receive this event message (multicasting FAN-OUT pattern) because the AEG doesn't balancing on the subscription level like we have it in the Azure Service Bus.

Comment: The AEG delivery and retry policy mechanism, also a validation of the webhook is an another point for using the pattern *Push-PushAck-Pull*,  where the event interest is reliable delivered to well-known available azure resource such as Azure Service Bus. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery)